# generalized vector multiplication without identity element

Tags: abstract-algebra, analysis

Is it possible to define (ideally infinitely) differentiable functions $f_n : \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ and $g_n : \mathbb{R}^n \times (\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ where $f_n(x, g_n(y, x)) = y$ and $f_n(x, y) = 0 \iff (x = 0 \vee y = 0)$?

It's possible for $n = 1$ using $f_1(x, y) = xy$ and $g_1(x, y) = \frac{x}{y}$.

By interpretation of $\mathbb{R}^2$ as complex numbers, it's also possible for $n = 2$ using $f_2(x, y) = \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 Re (x_1 + x_2 i) (y_1 + y_2 i) \\
 Im (x_1 + x_2 i) (y_1 + y_2 i) \\
\end{array}
\right)$ and $g_2(x, y) = \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 Re \frac{x_1 + x_2 i}{y_1 + y_2 i} \\
 Im \frac{x_1 + x_2 i}{y_1 + y_2 i} \\
\end{array}
\right)$.

$n = 4$ should also work using a similar approach using quaternions. But is it possible for the general case? I'm not sure whether this is related to this ([1]) question since it might not be necessary to have full algebraic characteristics in order to define $f_n$ and $g_n$.

[1] [Is there a third dimension of numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32100/is-there-a-third-dimension-of-numbers)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming only that $f_n$ and $g_n$ are continuous, and also assuming the existence of a special vector $e$ satisfying $f_n(x, e) = f_n(e, x) = x$, the existence of such functions would imply the existence of an [$H$-space structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-space) on $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{ 0 \}$, which is [homotopy equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy) to the sphere $S^{n-1}$.

It's a known but nontrivial result in [homotopy theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_theory), due to [Adams](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970147), that [$S^{n-1}$ has an $H$-space structure iff $n = 1, 2, 4, 8$](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/H-space#spheres), corresponding to the multiplication on the unit real numbers, the unit complex numbers, the unit quaternions, and the unit [octonions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octonion) respectively. So these are the only values of $n$ for which this is possible.

This is the most general and most difficult version of an easier result, namely the [classification of real division algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_(real_division_algebras)). In the simplest version of this result the multiplication is required to be bilinear (over $\mathbb{R}$) and associative (which excludes the octonions); next we drop associativity; and here we drop bilinearity.

I don't know what happens if you drop the requirement that $e$ exists. We do have $f_n(x, g_n(x, x)) = x$ so it may be possible to perform some kind of rescaling but it's tricky without either bilinearity or associativity.

Comment: Thanks, these are some very insightful pointers. However, I don't think I actually need $e$ to exist. Would you have any pointers on where to research the case without that requirement?

Comment: @ternary: I don't know. If no one answers here you might try asking on MathOverflow.